# Groovy/Grails Tool Suite Connect to Existing MySQL database

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'll preface this by saying this is the first time I'm working with Grails.

I'm trying to connect to an existing database, so that I can create domain classes from the database. I've installed the Grails Database Reverse Engineering Plugin (version 4.0.0) and I am using Grails 2.4.4. I've followed the steps in the [official user guide](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-db-reverse-engineer/v4/index.html) for the plugin and [here](https://objectpartners.com/2013/10/10/reverse-engineer-old-databases-with-grails/).

When I run the command "-Dgrails.env=extract db-reverse-engineer" I get the following error:

```
[groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:    startup failed:
[groovyc] Compile error during compilation with javac.
[groovyc] GenericResponseWrapper.java:203: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[groovyc]   @Override
[groovyc]   ^
[groovyc] PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:389: error: cannot find symbol
[groovyc]           contentType = response.getContentType();
[groovyc]                                 ^
[groovyc]   symbol:   method getContentType()
[groovyc]   location: variable response of type HttpServletResponse
[groovyc] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[groovyc] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[groovyc] 2 errors
[groovyc] 
[groovyc] 
[groovyc] 1 error
```

Hopefully I haven't left out too much information, please let me know what else I need to provide. Thank you.

Comment: Which jdk do you use?

Comment: JDK 1.8.0_66 (64 bit) on Windows

Comment: are you using other plugins in addition? https://vasya10.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/grails-plugin-dependency-issues/

Comment: I tried that site before. It's a fresh project. I'll post the answer I obtained from a colleague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so what solved it for me was switching to version 3.0.0 of the Grails Database Reverse Engineering Plugin and then also using Hibernate 3.x.x.. I also commented the line "compile ':cache:1.1.8'" in BuildConfig.groovy. Once the models are created, you can always remove the comment. I hope this helps someone!